# What does @ do in Dart programs?

Tags: dart, metadata

I've just spent 20 hours in learning about the basics of Dart language, but when I find the `@` prefix in an open-source Dart program such as [here](https://github.com/vsavkin/angulardart-sample-app/blob/master/web/talk_to_me_main.dart), which I found that most programs use, I wonder what the `@` directive do in those programs...

For your information, [the official documentation says the following](https://www.dartlang.org/docs/dart-up-and-running/contents/ch02.html#ch02-metadata):

> Metadata
>
> Use metadata to give additional information about your code. A metadata annotation begins with the character @, followed by either a reference to a compile-time constant (such as deprecated) or a call to a constant constructor.
>
> Three annotations are available to all Dart code: @deprecated, @override, and @proxy. For examples of using @override and @proxy, see the section called “Extending a Class”. Here’s an example of using the @deprecated annotation:

However, what "additional information" does the `@` directive add to the code? If you create an instance by writing the following constructor

```
@todo('seth', 'make this do something')
```

, instead of the following constructor, which is the default:

```
todo('seth", 'make this do something')
```

, what is the benefit I can get from the first constructor?

I've got that using the built-in metadata such as `@deprecated` and `@override` can give me an advantage of being warned in running the app, but what can I get from the case on the custom `@todo`, or the aforementioned linked sample code over Github?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do some 'reasoning' about code.
You can query for fields/methods/classes/libraries/... that have a specific annotation.
You acquire those code parts using reflection. In Dart reflection  is done by the 'dart:mirrors' package.

You can find an code example here: [How to retrieve metadata in Dartlang?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19492607)

An example where annotations are regularly used is for serialization or database persistence where you add metatdata to the class that can be used as configuration settings by the serialization/persistence framework to know how to process a field or method.

For example you add an `@Entity()` annotation to indicate that this class should be persisted.
On each field that should be persisted you add another annotation like `@Column()`.
Many persistence frameworks generate the database table automatically from this metadata.
For this they need more information so you add a `@Id()` on the field that should be used as primary key and `@Column(name: 'first_name', type: 'varchar', length: 32)` to define parameters for the database table and columns.
This is just an example. The limit is you imagination.

Answer (score 6):

Annotations can be accessed through the [dart:mirrors](https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/stable/dartdoc-viewer/dart-mirrors) library. You can use custom annotations whenever you want to provide additional information about a class, method, etc. For instance [@MirrorsUsed](https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/stable/dartdoc-viewer/dart%3amirrors.MirrorsUsed) is used to provide the dart2js compiler with extra information to optimize the size of the generated JavaScript.

Annotations are generally more useful to framework or library authors than application authors. For instance, if you were creating a REST server framework in Dart, you could use annotations to turn methods into web resources. For example it might look something like the following (assuming you have created the @GET annotation):

```dart
@GET('/users/')
List<User> getUsers() {
 // ...
}
```

You could then have your framework scan your code at server startup using mirrors to find all methods with the @GET annotation and bind the method to the URL specified in the annotation.